# Implement SOLID principles in Spring MVC Project with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, solid-principles, web-architecture

We are implementing Spring MVC project with Hibernate functionality. As per the sample implementation of SpringMVC, we would have different layers with the application. They include: Controller, Service, Entity & Repository. 
Business logic of the application is being implemented in Service layer. API given by Spring framework follows the Object Oriented Principles, we are just wandering how SOLID principles can be applied to the classes of the application. In other words, how SOLID principles can be applied to the Spring MVC Hibernate application

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit abstract so here is a general answer:

I would suggest to look at the differences between rich and anemic models.
Spring and Hibernate encourage using anemic model which is considered an anti pattern from Object Oriented Design point of view and 
makes it hard to apply SOLID principles.

More on this topic you can find in excellent book by Vaughn Vernon:
[https://www.amazon.com/Implementing-Domain-Driven-Design-Vaughn-Vernon/dp/0321834577](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321834577)

Domain Driven Design described in the book may be also of interest for you.

Comment: Thanks Andrey. I came across the Domain Driven Design and going through the book.